# Slow boot/resume from suspend

Tags: 14.04, boot, dual-boot, partitioning, suspend

I recently installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS alongside my Windows 8.1 on my laptop and have been enjoying it a lot. I realized some day that I wanted to give more space for my root and home partitions (they had 10GB and 10GB respectively), so I booted into Windows one day and shrunk one of the Windows partitions. I didn't have enough time to allocate that free space into these partitions immediately so I went to school after booting back into Ubuntu. Some time during the day, my laptop's battery died and when I had the chance to plug in and boot, I got an error that said “gave up waiting for root device” on a black screen.

After some googling, I found out that if I entered 'exit' as a command on this screen, it would load for a bit and the screen will flash, turning all text yellow and then boot normally. There were other ways to go around this error which includes

- Changing the SATA option from AHCI to IDE in the BIOS menu (completely bypasses the error screen)
- adding a rootdelay as suggested on the error screen

This wouldn't be such a big problem (although annoying) if it didn't make booting and waking from suspending really **really** slow. It takes around 30-60 seconds longer to get from start of system to the login screen. Even on waking from suspend, I have to wait at least 30 seconds before I can log back in. This is problematic as it has even affected my Windows boot times. When I first installed Ubuntu this error never occurred and boots were ultra fast and smooth.

Things that I have tried:

- Modifying my /etc/fstab to use dev/sdaX instead of UUIDs
- Reinstalling Ubuntu multiple times

Running GParted, I notice that there is an unknown partition and I don't know whether this is the problem.
[picture](http://i125.photobucket.com/albums/p66/limsijing/Screenshotfrom2014-10-11192530_zps501243a8.png)

This is really ruining my experience as I have a pretty fast computer and it shouldn't take so long for booting. Any help at all is appreciated

Specs:

- ASUS Vivobook S550CB
- Intel i7 3537U
- nVidia 740M
- 8GB RAM

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to diagnose/fix very slow boot on Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1030867/how-to-diagnose-fix-very-slow-boot-on-ubuntu-18-04)