# How to diagnose/fix very slow boot on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: boot, 18.04

There is a long time where SSD does nothing.

- How can I find the fault and fix it ?
- Already checked `/etc/fstab`, no swap or anything wrong there (32GB of RAM, no swap)

```
[    2.173492] usb 2-1.6: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[    2.173497] usb 2-1.6: Product: DW375 Bluetooth Module
[    2.173501] usb 2-1.6: Manufacturer: Dell Computer Corp
[    2.173511] usb 2-1.6: SerialNumber: 7CE9D3C0713B
[    2.323728] ata4: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
[    2.441062] input: AlpsPS/2 ALPS GlidePoint as /devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input6
[    2.640309] ata5: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
[    2.954947] ata6: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
[    3.068090] clocksource: Switched to clocksource tsc
[   36.584826] EXT4-fs (sda1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[   36.726117] ip_tables: (C) 2000-2006 Netfilter Core Team
[   36.732610] systemd[1]: systemd 237 running in system mode. (+PAM +AUDIT +SELINUX +IMA +APPARMOR +SMACK +SYSVINIT +UTMP +LIBCRYPTSETUP +GCRYPT +GNUTLS +AC
L +XZ +LZ4 +SECCOMP +BLKID +ELFUTILS +KMOD -IDN2 +IDN -PCRE2 default-hierarchy=hybrid)
[   36.751996] systemd[1]: Detected architecture x86-64.
[   36.753867] systemd[1]: Set hostname to <latitude-e5520>.
[   36.868561] systemd[1]: Started Forward Password Requests to Wall Directory Watch.
[   36.868594] systemd[1]: Reached target Remote File Systems.
[   36.868751] systemd[1]: Created slice User and Session Slice.
[   36.868869] systemd[1]: Created slice System Slice.
[   36.868948] systemd[1]: Listening on udev Control Socket.
[   36.868957] systemd[1]: Reached target Slices.
[   36.868996] systemd[1]: Listening on udev Kernel Socket.
[   36.895156] EXT4-fs (sda1): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro
[   36.898185] lp: driver loaded but no devices found
[   36.903941] ppdev: user-space parallel port driver
```

Comment: Is this a fresh install? with lvm? perhaps this bug : https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1768230 ?

Comment: To see the `WARNING:Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to device scanning.` message, you should disable the spash/quiet boot (see : https://askubuntu.com/a/289/454520)

Comment: It's about long network.service booting. Solution from [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/887458/420550) answer helped me.

Comment: I had deleted the SWAP partition, which caused this same error. To solve this problem, I regenerated the INITRAMFS: `sudo update-initramfs -u`

Answer (score 78, accepted):

I upgraded to 18.04 today and encountered the same issue. I was able to fix it by booting the kernel with the `noresume` parameter.

Like you, I also have no swap space. At some point during the upgrade, the initramfs config was modified, adding a line pointing to a nonexistent swap partition. The slow boot was because it was looking for this partition and then timing out after 30 seconds.

To update GRUB so that it passes this option to the kernel automatically on boot:

1. Edit the file `/etc/default/grub` file so that the string `noresume` is included in the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` line, for example:

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash noresume"
   ```
2. Run this command to update GRUB:

   ```
   sudo update-grub
   ```
3. Reboot the computer

Comment: noresume fixed it, nothing strange in initramfs.

Comment: I upgraded to 18.04 yesterday and I had the same problem (it took 52 seconds to boot). After setting the "noresume" parameter, it took 21 seconds.

Comment: You could improve your already good answer with instructions on updating grub.

Comment: Please note that this is a workaroud, since it will prevent resuming a hibernated system.

Comment: I'm worried that this might prevent me from using hibernation. However this worked for me: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1013830/slow-boot-long-kernel-load-time-due-to-wrong-resume-device (editing /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume, changing RESUME=none from the UUID and running update-initramfs -u)

Comment: I'm running Oracle VirtualBox and can't even log into the Ubuntu instance - how do I fix the "lvmetad is not active yet" issue? My complete questions is posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56431425/windows-virtual-box-with-ubuntu-unable-to-boot

Comment: I had deleted the SWAP partition, which caused this same error. To solve this problem, I regenerated the INITRAMFS: `sudo update-initramfs -u`

Answer (score 32):

```
$ systemd-analyze blame
```

Look to see which processes are taking the most time of the boot process.

Comment: `systemd-analyze blame` will not show kernel time, and for this problem. `systemd-analyse time` will show that it's the kernel that is stuck searching for the filesystem.

Comment: good hint, but the longest process took only 1.6seconds, so this tool did not help.

Comment: @Pim `systemd-analyse time` has a typo, it should have a `z`

Comment: `systemd-analyze critical-chain` is even better than `blame`

Comment: below is the output for blame...now how do i improve the time runs of the longest running jobs ??systemd-analyze blame
         22.866s systemd-journal-flush.service
         22.844s dev-sda1.device
         16.689s ufw.service
         16.041s systemd-modules-load.service
         15.367s keyboard-setup.service
         13.714s systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
          9.229s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
          7.599s snapd.service
          rest are lesser than 6 seconds. pls guide, i'm a newbie

Answer (score 14):

What worked for me was to run `sudo rm /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume` followed by `sudo update-initramfs -u` . This seems to be a regression from an upgrade (see https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=861151).

Comment: Worked great. Seems cleaner to me than adding the "noresume" kernel argument to GRUB (which also worked).

Answer (score 10):

I upgraded to 18.04 from 16.04. Boot time was more than 10 minutes.
Tried from "No splash screen to Kernel" to find which processes are taking the most time for booting.

```
A start job is running for Raise network interfaces (1min 26s / 5min 24s)
```

So, we need to reduce time for this process to save boot time. To do so,

You have to edit,

```
sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/network-online.target.wants/networking.service
```

Find

```
TimeoutStartSec=5min
```

Change to

```
TimeoutStartSec=5s
```

and reboot

Comment: This is where my boot was burning a lot of time, so this solution worked for me. +1

Comment: It was my case... Just I had to insert the line in `/etc/systemd/system/network-online.target.wants/NetworkManager-wait-online.service` file, under `[Service]` because it wasn't already there. I'm on Lubuntu 20.04. thank you

Answer (score 7):

You can configure the timeout for Start Job and Stop Jobs.

Edit `/etc/systemd/system.conf` with elevated privileges and change/add two lines that are commented by default from 90 seconds to 5 (or whatever you prefer) and uncomment it:

from:

```bsh
#DefaultTimeoutStartSec=90s
#DefaultTimeoutStopSec=90s
```

to:

```bsh
DefaultTimeoutStartSec=5s
DefaultTimeoutStopSec=5s
```

After that, apply the changes by rebuilding your initramfs with the command:

```bsh
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

Comment: this solved my problem after doing `Gparted` repartition operations on SSD drive which took notably longer boot time otherwise.

Comment: Not always work. On the contrary: system need to be restart in recovery mode and redo the changes.

Answer (score 0):

I tried a different method but nothing it worked. then I find it was the graphics driver issue. I solved by using additional drivers for me it was Nvidia.

goto: software & updates -> choose listed graphics driver -> apply changes

Note: I am using kernel version 4.18.0-25-generic