# Slow boot time on fresh minimal install of 18.04

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 18.04

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 minimal fresh install with dual boot Windows 10 on a Samsung 850 EVO SSD.

```
$ systemd-analyze time              
Startup finished in 17.129s (firmware) + 3.573s (loader) + 3.058s (kernel) + 22.988s (userspace) = 46.750s
graphical.target reached after 22.981s in userspace

$ systemd-analyze blame | head -n 10
         20.674s plymouth-quit-wait.service
          5.077s bolt.service
          3.252s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
          1.483s docker.service
           863ms dev-sda4.device
           820ms snap-gnome\x2dlogs-31.mount
           787ms fwupd.service
           742ms systemd-resolved.service
           690ms snap-gnome\x2dsystem\x2dmonitor-39.mount
           546ms dev-loop2.device
```

Any ideas why boot time takes so long? Even my Windows 10 partition boots up faster.

Comment: Same problem here. In my case, it seems it was something related with LVM. Fortunately, I was able to find the solution following this tutorial: https://www.hiroom2.com/2018/05/01/ubuntu-1804-lvm-swap-wait-for-root-en/ From more than 40 seconds to boot, now I get less than 20. I would like to thank the autor of the referred article for the fix.

Comment: Thanks for the comment but I'm not using LVM here.

Comment: The solution is not about LVM only. It is about specifying the correct swap partition to avoid unecessary delay/timeout. Have you tried also the noresume solution below ?

Answer (score 4):

As answered in this [similar question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1030867/ubuntu-18-04-how-to-diagnose-fix-very-slow-boot/1031667), it may be possible to workaround/resolve this issue by passing the `noresume` option to the kernel.

To update GRUB so that it passes this option to the kernel automatically on boot:

1. [edit](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/KernelBootParameters#Permanently_Add_a_Kernel_Boot_Parameter) the `/etc/default/grub` file so that the string `noresume` is included in the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` variable:

   > `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash noresume"`
2. run this command to update grub: `sudo update-grub`
3. reboot the computer

Comment: I have done that but my ubuntu freezes after boot, I can't move my mouse or type anything and none of my auto start programs start

Comment: @mormaii2 - that sounds like you might be missing the modules-extra package for the kernel you are trying to boot into.  try running `dpkg -l | grep modules-extra` to ensure that such a package exists for that kernel. if its not there, make sure to install it with apt

Comment: I do have it installed: 

linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-20-generic      
4.15.0-20.21 
Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.15.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP