# After upgrade 17.10 -> 18.04 I get: Failed to connect to lvmetad

Tags: boot, upgrade, 18.04

after the recent update to 18.04 from 17.10 I'm thrown into the terminal at boot with the error message:
Warning: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to device scanning
Gave up waiting for suspend/remove device
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root: clean, 299019/14557104 files, 52547827/58210304 blocks

I've tried the solutions to fix lvmetad I could find here but nothing has worked so far. I would really appreciate some help!

Mikael

Comment: There is a bug report about this: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1768230

Comment: Good to know. I did a clean reinstall instead.

Comment: Seems like I jumped the gun a bit, clean install... I was just assuming it would install fine. It's actually crashing when I try to!

Comment: If someone stumbles upon this and has a crashing installer, try to build the USB drive with etcher.io at first I used Rufus and switching to etcher fixed it for me.

Answer (score 2):

I had this same problem, and it seems to be two problems.

First, there is the error message which has to do with the bug report. It reflects a long boot time that can be shortened using the directions at [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1030867/ubuntu-18-04-how-to-diagnose-fix-very-slow-boot/1031667#1031667), as long as you do not mind disabling hibernation. It will *not* remove the error message, but it will dramatically speed up the boot time.

Second, there is the lack of graphical display. This can be fixed by running

```
sudo systemctl start gdm
```

This starts `gdm3`, the Gnome login display. For me, the change persisted, so even after rebooting, I did not need to reenter this command.