# Ubuntu 18.04 purple screen stays a long time before splash

Tags: boot, 18.04

I've installed Ubuntu 18.04 (single boot) on a trusty old Dell Latitude E6400. It works very well, but before the Ubuntu Splash screen, right after BIOS boot, a purple screen starts and stays for several (about 20) seconds (as if it was a screen to choose what OS to boot, but this is blank purple), and then the splash screen appears and quickly the login screen. I type the password and a purple screen again which hangs for two or three seconds and then I use the system normally (at least so I think, because my use is very light, really); is all that normal?

I remember I had Ubuntu 16.04 dual boot with MSW7 on a desktop with a basic similar configuration to the Dell laptop and after choosing Ubuntu would go to splash, quickly booting.

Sorry, should've put more information.

```
systemd-analyze critical-chain
graphical.target @43.688s
└─multi-user.target @43.688s
  └─kerneloops.service @36.825s +15ms
    └─network-online.target @36.822s
      └─NetworkManager-wait-online.service @30.287s +6.534s
        └─NetworkManager.service @26.812s +3.472s
          └─dbus.service @26.509s
            └─basic.target @26.472s
              └─sockets.target @26.472s
                └─snapd.socket @26.435s +35ms
                  └─sysinit.target @26.418s
                    └─cryptsetup.target @26.418s
                      └─systemd-ask-password-wall.path @3.936s
                        └─-.mount @3.859s
                          └─system.slice @3.886s
                            └─-.slice @3.859s
```

```
 systemd-analyze blame
         22.416s dev-sda1.device
         21.133s systemd-journal-flush.service
         14.562s systemd-sysctl.service
         14.209s keyboard-setup.service
         13.383s plymouth-quit-wait.service
         13.044s systemd-udevd.service
         10.576s fwupd.service
          6.534s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
          6.212s plymouth-start.service
          5.086s snapd.service
          4.514s apparmor.service
          3.472s NetworkManager.service
          3.468s apt-daily-upgrade.service
          3.271s udisks2.service
          3.045s systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
          2.589s accounts-daemon.service
          2.535s ModemManager.service
          2.350s thermald.service
          2.007s networkd-dispatcher.service
          1.818s snap-gnome\x2dcharacters-117.mount
          1.817s plymouth-read-write.service
          1.817s console-setup.service
          1.815s dns-clean.service
          1.750s snap-gnome\x2dsystem\x2dmonitor-54.mount
          1.699s snap-gnome\x2dlogs-43.mount
          1.642s snap-gnome\x2dcharacters-103.mount
          1.639s snap-gnome\x2dsystem\x2dmonitor-51.mount
          1.609s systemd-modules-load.service
          1.559s snap-core-5145.mount
          1.218s snap-gtk\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-701.mount
          1.107s snap-gnome\x2dcalculator-238.mount
          1.048s systemd-random-seed.service
          1.044s snap-core-4917.mount
          1.033s snap-gnome\x2dcalculator-199.mount
           964ms snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d26\x2d1604-59.mount
           958ms snap-gtk\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-319.mount
           934ms snap-gnome\x2dcharacters-124.mount
           934ms dev-loop10.device
           934ms grub-common.service
           933ms snap-gnome\x2dlogs-37.mount
           889ms wpa_supplicant.service
           822ms dev-loop19.device
           695ms swapfile.swap
           686ms snap-gnome\x2dlogs-40.mount
           540ms avahi-daemon.service
           500ms dev-loop15.device
           456ms systemd-journald.service
           418ms user@120.service
           415ms ufw.service
           382ms apport.service
           375ms packagekit.service
           357ms gpu-manager.service
           357ms speech-dispatcher.service
           341ms gdm.service
           339ms snap-gnome\x2dsystem\x2dmonitor-57.mount
           337ms rsyslog.service
           333ms pppd-dns.service
           304ms systemd-logind.service
           301ms snap-core-5328.mount
           254ms systemd-remount-fs.service
           245ms snap-gnome\x2dcalculator-222.mount
           242ms snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d26\x2d1604-70.mount
           228ms dev-hugepages.mount
           207ms dev-loop8.device
           198ms upower.service
           183ms sys-kernel-debug.mount
           173ms dev-mqueue.mount
           170ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
           147ms systemd-timesyncd.service
           134ms systemd-resolved.service
           132ms systemd-udev-trigger.service
           124ms kmod-static-nodes.service
           118ms user@1000.service
           104ms dev-loop17.device
           104ms dev-loop16.device
           103ms dev-loop14.device
           103ms dev-loop13.device
           102ms dev-loop12.device
           101ms dev-loop11.device
           101ms dev-loop9.device
           100ms dev-loop7.device
           100ms dev-loop6.device
            97ms dev-loop2.device
            97ms networking.service
            90ms dev-loop5.device
            89ms dev-loop4.device
            89ms dev-loop3.device
            89ms dev-loop0.device
            88ms dev-loop1.device
            87ms dev-loop18.device
            74ms colord.service
            60ms bolt.service
            60ms polkit.service
            59ms systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service
            48ms systemd-update-utmp.service
            43ms snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d26\x2d1604-64.mount
            35ms snapd.socket
            35ms systemd-rfkill.service
            35ms resolvconf.service
            33ms snapd.seeded.service
            28ms systemd-backlight@backlight:acpi_video0.service
            24ms setvtrgb.service
            24ms alsa-restore.service
            17ms systemd-backlight@leds:dell::kbd_backlight.service
            15ms kerneloops.service
            12ms systemd-backlight@backlight:intel_backlight.service
            10ms ureadahead-stop.service
             9ms systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service
             9ms systemd-user-sessions.service
             8ms resolvconf-pull-resolved.service
             6ms rtkit-daemon.service
             6ms sys-kernel-config.mount
             4ms sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount
```

My system isn't partitioned. Video card is Intel Mobile 4 Series Chipset; driver=i915.

[Full `dmesg` output](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/N4Vq4HwTwt/).

Answer (score 3):

It would be helpful if you would edit your question to give more information about the issue. I am having the same problem and haven't found an answer for it yet, but I did found some interesting leads that you could maybe try and we could learn together about the problem.

- Is your "purple-screen-time" timed when you use the `systemd-analyze` command in the terminal? (My system appears to start to count the startup time only after the purple screen). It would be helpful to add the results from this command to your question. Other commands that might show different places where your system is hanging are `systemd-analyze critical-chain` and `systemd-analyze blame`.

Known issues could be:

- Is your system partitioned? (or had SWAP partitions before?)

  It could be the same issue as described here [How to diagnose/fix very slow boot on Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1030867/how-to-diagnose-fix-very-slow-boot-on-ubuntu-18-04). Your system might be trying to access a nonexistent SWAP partition.

  The suggested answer there is to update grub.

  > Update GRUB so that it passes this option to the kernel automatically on boot:
  >
  > ```
  > Edit the file /etc/default/grub file so that the string noresume is included in the GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT line, for example:
  >
  > GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash noresume"
  >
  > Run this command to update GRUB:
  >
  > sudo update-grub
  >
  > Reboot the computer
  > ```

  Is that helpful for you? (It didn't work for me).
- Do you use a Logical Volume Manager (LVM)?

  Your system could also be having trouble with a LVM, [like in this case](https://www.hiroom2.com/2018/05/01/ubuntu-1804-lvm-swap-wait-for-root-en/). You should maybe check if that answer is helpful for you.
- A third issue might be caused by a NVidia graphics card. What is your graphic card and which drivers are you using for it? Nvidia proprietary or Xorg?

  [This issue here](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1033103/ubuntu-18-04-lts-boot-up-time-increases-by-over-100-after-installing-nvidia-drivers/) was resolved by updating the NVidia drivers.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/878490)

Comment: Thanks! I understand the community rules. It is just sad that this is one of those cases in which the rules end up blocking information exchange.
Can I get somebody's help to transform this into a comment, perhaps?

Comment: Actually this is an answer. It speculates about possible causes of the problem and offers respective solutions. It collates information from the author's research and will help others with the same problem. +1

Comment: I don't know much of anything. I've tried the "no resume" fix and it didn't work. I don't know anything about LVM (read and heard some, though). And graphics card is Intel (as per my edit).

Comment: Thanks for the new information. Could you also post the results for dmesg, please? I continued research and found some new possibilities for this issue, but I won't be able to write them here today. I hope to be able to write during the weekend.

Comment: Isn't dmesg a very long output? It won't fit in the question. If there's any way to attach a file to my question let me know (I've saved a less output). Thanks.

Comment: @A.Alencar you can put it on http://paste.ubuntu.com and post the link

Comment: OK. Here's the link to dmesg-log: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/N4Vq4HwTwt/