# Slow booting Ubuntu

Tags: boot, system-installation, ram

I recently removed windows 10 and I reinstalled my laptop's OS to Ubuntu latest version till 13/09/2018 with 2Gb ram and 1Tb hard disk with no graphics card. I probably loaded Ubuntu as I thought this will make my pc faster since it was lagging too much before. But after loading Ubuntu, I found out that it works slower even during booting. It almost takes around 2 minutes to completely start my pc. Also, after that, it works slowly. I'm new in changing OS. Please, can anyone help me get my pc to boot fast and run fast?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to diagnose/fix very slow boot on Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1030867/how-to-diagnose-fix-very-slow-boot-on-ubuntu-18-04)