# Slow boot after upgrade ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04 LTS

Tags: boot, 18.04, upgrade

I have recently upgraded ubuntu and booting is really slow... (i'm running dual boot with windows 10).

I tried solutions posted previously :
[How to diagnose/fix very slow boot on Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1030867/how-to-diagnose-fix-very-slow-boot-on-ubuntu-18-04)

but it didn't work. Also tried to set : 
    /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume 
with resume=none but it didn't work neither

```
Startup finished in 3.798s (firmware) + 13.346s (loader) + 5.547s (kernel) + 5min 37.536s (userspace) = 6min 229ms  graphical.target reached after 5min 37.513s in userspace
```

When looking boot.log it appears that something is happening when "A start job is running for Raise network interfaces"

```
[K[[0;1;31mFAILED[0m] Failed to start Raise network interfaces. See 'systemctl status networking.service' for details.
```

But i dont know how should i fix it. Any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Network Manager, try replacing it with Wicd. Reboot the system, uninstall `network-manager`, configure Wicd and enjoy.

Comment: This has been merged into your original answer. Click *edit* under your answer next time.

Comment: Actually it worked, booting time is now around 2 mins... Do you know why ?

Comment: No, I don't, I suppose that NM has some kind of bug in timeouts waiting for daemons responses. But I think that 2 minutes are still too much for boot, my system spends less than 8 seconds at boot. I think your system needs more tuning.