# Ubuntu boot time very slow and freezes after suspension

Tags: boot, 18.10, dmesg

So after updating to 18.10 from ubuntu 18.04 my laptop is booting slowly and some times it freezes and i'm force to reboot

My laptop specs
[image: Here are the details of my pc (Ram, HDD, Processor, etc)]
some info that might help find the issue.

```
➜  ~ systemd-analyze      
Startup finished in 4.604s (firmware) + 4.819s (loader) + 3.729s (kernel) + 1min 7.831s (userspace) = 1min 20.985s
graphical.target reached after 1min 5.351s in userspace
➜  ~ systemd-analyze blame

         28.687s postgresql@10-main.service
         24.988s dev-sda2.device
         18.408s systemd-journal-flush.service
         16.287s ModemManager.service
         16.195s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
         15.235s snapd.service
         13.579s preload.service
         13.383s dev-loop33.device
         13.325s dev-loop25.device
         13.184s dev-loop29.device
         13.139s udisks2.service
         12.751s dev-loop31.device
         12.746s dev-loop27.device
         12.515s dev-loop23.device
         12.445s dev-loop32.device
         12.345s plymouth-quit-wait.service
         12.231s dev-loop34.device
         11.973s dev-loop26.device
         11.730s dev-loop18.device
         11.685s dev-loop20.device
         11.673s networkd-dispatcher.service
         11.563s dev-loop28.device
         11.556s dev-loop24.device
         11.466s dev-loop14.device
         11.432s dev-loop30.device
         11.268s accounts-daemon.service
         11.019s dev-loop15.device
         10.996s dev-loop19.device
         10.934s dev-loop21.device
         10.912s NetworkManager.service
         10.622s dev-loop12.device
         10.521s dev-loop16.device
         10.519s dev-loop22.device
         10.339s dev-loop9.device
         10.303s dev-loop17.device
         10.256s dev-loop13.device
          9.496s dev-loop11.device
          9.451s dev-loop10.device
          9.247s dev-loop8.device
          8.033s dev-loop4.device
          8.025s avahi-daemon.service
          7.893s networking.service
          7.800s apport.service
          7.742s sysstat.service
          7.651s gpu-manager.service
          7.603s systemd-logind.service
          7.570s rsyslog.service
```

[Full dmesg output.](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/ygFQg8dvtQ/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to diagnose/fix very slow boot on Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1030867/how-to-diagnose-fix-very-slow-boot-on-ubuntu-18-04)