# Ubuntu 18.04.2LTS very slow to boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

My system has become very slow - it used to boot in 15 secs. Now it takes more than 3 minutes to boot. I've a dell with dual boot (ubuntu and windows) I have been reading about swap disk allocation and other nvidia related issues. Nothing seem to improve my boot speed.

```
systemd-analyze time
```

Startup finished in 5.680s (firmware) + 3.578s (loader) + 33.469s (kernel) + 3min 475ms (userspace) = 3min 43.204s
graphical.target reached after 1min 36.087s in userspace

results of systemd-anlayze blame

```
5.105s nmbd.service
      1.281s keyboard-setup.service
      1.256s unifi.service
      1.051s dev-sda5.device
      1.049s snapd.service
       816ms plymouth-start.service
       815ms fwupd.service
       805ms systemd-backlight@backlight:intel_backlight.service
       764ms apparmor.service
       689ms plymouth-read-write.service
       610ms snapd.seeded.service
       513ms systemd-journal-flush.service
       463ms NetworkManager.service
       355ms systemd-logind.service
       330ms systemd-rfkill.service
       295ms networkd-dispatcher.service
       230ms upower.service
       224ms udisks2.service
       161ms systemd-resolved.service
       159ms systemd-timesyncd.service
       158ms snap-core-6964.mount
       157ms snap-mailspring-277.mount
       152ms accounts-daemon.service
       142ms lightdm.service
       140ms plymouth-quit-wait.service
       129ms ModemManager.service
       124ms snap-rclone-453.mount
       122ms systemd-udevd.service
       122ms thermald.service
       120ms apport.service
       115ms snap-rclone-466.mount
       114ms grub-common.service
       111ms systemd-udev-trigger.service
       111ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
       108ms systemd-journald.service
       106ms snap-mailspring-346.mount
        97ms snap-core-5897.mount
        93ms alsa-restore.service
        93ms bluetooth.service
        83ms pppd-dns.service
        82ms avahi-daemon.service
        78ms rsyslog.service
        78ms gpu-manager.service
        76ms systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-4EF8\x2dD105.service
        71ms dev-loop9.device
        71ms snap-rclone-446.mount
        69ms bolt.service
        68ms dev-loop8.device
        66ms systemd-modules-load.service
        63ms dev-loop5.device
        60ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
        59ms snap-gtk\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-1198.mount
        56ms user@1000.service
        55ms packagekit.service
        52ms wpa_supplicant.service
        51ms smbd.service
        46ms dev-loop7.device
        45ms colord.service
        45ms binfmt-support.service
        43ms speech-dispatcher.service
        41ms dns-clean.service
        40ms snap-mailspring-284.mount
        34ms kerneloops.service
        34ms systemd-remount-fs.service
        33ms dev-loop6.device
        28ms networking.service
        26ms dev-loop3.device
        26ms snap-core-6673.mount
        25ms dev-loop0.device
        23ms proc-sys-fs-binfmt_misc.mount
        22ms geoclue.service
        21ms polkit.service
        21ms systemd-sysctl.service
        20ms systemd-random-seed.service
        19ms dev-loop1.device
        18ms boot-efi.mount
        14ms systemd-update-utmp.service
        13ms dev-mqueue.mount
        12ms ureadahead-stop.service
        11ms resolvconf.service
        11ms systemd-user-sessions.service
        11ms console-setup.service
        10ms sys-kernel-debug.mount
         9ms ufw.service
         9ms systemd-backlight@leds:dell::kbd_backlight.service
         9ms sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount
         8ms dev-hugepages.mount
         7ms systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service
         6ms kmod-static-nodes.service
         6ms resolvconf-pull-resolved.service
         6ms rtkit-daemon.service
         6ms dev-loop2.device
         5ms snapd.socket
         4ms sys-kernel-config.mount
         4ms setvtrgb.service
         1ms dev-loop4.device
```

What can i do to improve the boot time?

`systemd-analyze critical-chain
graphical.target @1min 36.189s
└─multi-user.target @1min 36.189s
  └─smbd.service @1min 36.077s +111ms
    └─nmbd.service @1min 30.933s +5.143s
      └─network-online.target @1min 30.930s
        └─network.target @1min 30.928s
          └─NetworkManager.service @1min 30.485s +442ms
            └─dbus.service @1min 30.437s
              └─basic.target @1min 30.406s
                └─sockets.target @1min 30.405s
                  └─snapd.socket @1min 30.401s +4ms
                    └─sysinit.target @1min 30.400s
                      └─apparmor.service @1.633s +630ms
                        └─local-fs.target @1.630s
                          └─run-user-1000-gvfs.mount @1min 43.717s
                            └─run-user-1000.mount @1min 43.472s
                              └─local-fs-pre.target @1.442s
                                └─keyboard-setup.service @169ms +1.272s
                                  └─systemd-journald.socket @156ms
                                    └─system.slice @156ms
                                      └─-.slice @154ms`

Comment: Maybe add the output of `systemd-analyze critical-chain` as it might show more as to where things might be hanging.

Comment: here is the output:

Comment: It is looking like some of the biggest gaps are happening after the fs (file system) stuff.  You might want to see https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/bootup.html  Maybe you have something enabled in your `/etc/fstab` file that runs a filesystem check on every reboot.  It is under the pass settings, see:  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab  This is only a guess on my part.  Someone else may see something different than me.  +1 for visibility here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to diagnose/fix very slow boot on Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1030867/how-to-diagnose-fix-very-slow-boot-on-ubuntu-18-04)

Answer (score 0):

Try to check if you have a swap partition, and if you do, then try to see if it is a correct UUID of that one set in the /etc/fstab