# Ubuntu Kernel Boot very slow - time skip at "raid6: sse2x1 gen() 858 MB/s"

Tags: boot, server, 18.04, kernel

There is this time skip during *kernel boot*:

```
Jul 19 14:07:02 deetabokkusu kernel: [    2.874776] hub 1-1.4:1.0: USB hub found
Jul 19 14:07:02 deetabokkusu kernel: [    2.877993] hub 1-1.4:1.0: 4 ports detected
Jul 19 14:07:02 deetabokkusu kernel: [   94.080339] raid6: sse2x1   gen()   858 MB/s
Jul 19 14:07:02 deetabokkusu kernel: [   94.128306] raid6: sse2x1   xor()  2371 MB/s
Jul 19 14:07:02 deetabokkusu kernel: [   94.176324] raid6: sse2x2   gen()  1730 MB/s
Jul 19 14:07:02 deetabokkusu kernel: [   94.224328] raid6: sse2x2   xor()  2816 MB/s
Jul 19 14:07:02 deetabokkusu kernel: [   94.272285] raid6: sse2x4   gen()  2430 MB/s
Jul 19 14:07:02 deetabokkusu kernel: [   94.320302] raid6: sse2x4   xor()  2333 MB/s
Jul 19 14:07:02 deetabokkusu kernel: [   94.323121] raid6: using algorithm sse2x4 gen() 2430 MB/s
Jul 19 14:07:02 deetabokkusu kernel: [   94.325949] raid6: .... xor() 2333 MB/s, rmw enabled
Jul 19 14:07:02 deetabokkusu kernel: [   94.328762] raid6: using ssse3x2 recovery algorithm
Jul 19 14:07:02 deetabokkusu kernel: [   94.335698] xor: measuring software checksum speed
Jul 19 14:07:02 deetabokkusu kernel: [   94.376549]    prefetch64-sse:  7668.000 MB/sec
Jul 19 14:07:02 deetabokkusu kernel: [   94.416564]    generic_sse:  6661.000 MB/sec
Jul 19 14:07:02 deetabokkusu kernel: [   94.419385] xor: using function: prefetch64-sse (7668.000 MB/sec)
Jul 19 14:07:02 deetabokkusu kernel: [   94.426733] async_tx: api initialized (async)
Jul 19 14:07:02 deetabokkusu kernel: [   94.555496] Btrfs loaded, crc32c=crc32c-intel
```

`systemd-analyze` returns:

`Startup finished in 1min 34.896s (kernel) + 38.914s (userspace) = 2min 13.810s
graphical.target reached after 5.169s in userspace`

`systemd-analyze blame` returns:

`25.913s apt-daily.service
 9.181s apt-daily-upgrade.service
 2.131s dev-sda2.device
 1.325s snapd.service
 729ms media-duraibu1.mount
 717ms networkd-dispatcher.service`

I am **not** running a RAID on the system. What do I have to change for the kernel to boot more quickly?

**Edit:**
What I am interested in is the **kernel boot time** of **1 min 34.896s**. I know how to improve the userspace boot time of 38.914s with the information `systemd-analyze blame` gave me.

**Edit 2:**
Booting with two other LTS Kernels (v4.19.59 and v4.14.133) did not change the problem

Comment: Run this and see maybe some systemd service take up time `systemd-analyze blame`.

Comment: `system-analyze blame` only shows the time up take for userspace services, doesn't it? the highest uptake is "3.290s dev-sda2.device"  -> that seems ok to me.
the problem is the kernel startup time which is at 1min 35.095s as shown by `systemd-analyze`:
`Startup finished in 1min 35.095s (kernel) + 3.321s (userspace) = 1min 38.416s
`

Comment: What is your kernel version? Did you try booting with previous kernel version?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Kernel is Linux 4.15.0-54-generic x86_64. 
no i did not try that yet... how do I do that?
and: isn't there a way to get more information on what exactly is taking so long during the kernel startup?

Comment: When booting from grub menu select **Advanced options for Ubuntu** and from that pick the second kernel version. As @MichalPrzybylowicz said early run `systemd-analyze blame` to find out what is taking so long. Note you posted same question on SuperUser: https://superuser.com/questions/1461801/ubuntu-kernel-boot-stuck-at-raid6-sse2x1-gen-858-mb-s Did you opt for `btrfs` file system instead of conventional `ext4` file system?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix I added the return of `systemd-analyze blame` to my post. But as I pointed out earlier it does not help me with my problem as it only shows me the time uptake of services that start during *userspace startup*. I am interested in the services that start during *kernel startup* which consume way more time.
I'll look into changing the file system and booting with a different kernel version and post my results later!

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix booting with previous kernel did not change the problem

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to diagnose/fix very slow boot on Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1030867/how-to-diagnose-fix-very-slow-boot-on-ubuntu-18-04)