# Slow Boot after update to kernel 5.11.6 on ubuntu 20.04.2.0

Tags: boot, 20.04, kernel

My system is **Ubuntu 20.04.2.0 LTS(the newest LTS version)**.I just install via the .iso file and update the **kernel to 5.11.6**. I didn't do anything else on it.
The time after I enter my password is not long,but the time between I start the OS in VMware and the login interface exixts is about **2min** (but the time I update the kernel before is within 10s).
I have just tried almost every way in [How to diagnose/fix very slow boot on Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1030867/how-to-diagnose-fix-very-slow-boot-on-ubuntu-18-04).
I'm sure the problem is not about swap partition UUID because the system don't have one,and the /etc/fstab file is the same as the original version。
This is the analysis of the time and I think it is acceptable,but the time before the login interface exixts is so maddening,please help me!!

```
>>systemd-analyze && systemd-analyze critical-chain && systemd-analyze blame
Startup finished in 4.369s (kernel) + 3.417s (userspace) = 7.786s 
graphical.target reached after 3.409s in userspace
The time when unit became active or started is printed after the "@" character.
The time the unit took to start is printed after the "+" character.

graphical.target @3.409s
└─multi-user.target @3.409s
  └─snapd.seeded.service @3.375s +33ms
    └─snapd.service @1.934s +1.437s
      └─basic.target @1.888s
        └─sockets.target @1.887s
          └─snapd.socket @1.886s +981us
            └─sysinit.target @1.883s
              └─systemd-timesyncd.service @1.722s +160ms
                └─systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service @1.683s +31ms
                  └─local-fs.target @1.679s
                    └─boot-efi.mount @1.667s +11ms
                      └─systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-FB87\x2d3FDF.service @>
                        └─dev-disk-by\x2duuid-FB87\x2d3FDF.device @1.635s
```

Comment: Could you add how specifically you installed kernel 5.11? There are many ways. I believe there are no Ubuntu patches added to 5.11 kernel.