# Very slow boot Ubuntu 20.04 (7 mins)

Tags: boot, dual-boot

i'm new using Linux.

Recently i've installed Ubuntu and it starts very veeeeeery slowly (around to 7 mins), when Windows starts in 20 sec or less.

I have this:

```
    :~$ systemd-analyze
Bootup is not yet finished (org.freedesktop.systemd1.Manager.FinishTimestampMonotonic=0).
Please try again later.
Hint: Use 'systemctl list-jobs' to see active jobs
```

and this

```
~$ systemctl list-jobs
JOB UNIT                                 TYPE  STATE  
117 system-getty.slice                   start waiting
1   graphical.target                     start waiting
151 systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service start waiting
62  setvtrgb.service                     start waiting
2   multi-user.target                    start waiting
114 plymouth-quit-wait.service           start running

6 jobs listed.
```

I've tried changing the grub file:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

to

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash profile"
```

and then back to "quiet splash" again. But actually it got worse

What can I do?

Comment: Update Your question with output from command `systemd-analyze blame` once You complete boot process.

Answer (score 0):

welcome to AskUbuntu. Can you take a look at this link [enter link description here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1030867/how-to-diagnose-fix-very-slow-boot-on-ubuntu-18-04) Although this is about 18.04 this might help.