# Slow boot time in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, nvidia, cuda, nvidia-geforce

My computer takes 130 seconds to boot. I have a
Dell Vostro 5568 ,
cpu : Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-7200U CPU @ 2.50GHz
gpu : Nvidia geforce 940mx gpu with 4gb memory.

Is it reasonable for me to expect startup times less than 10seconds? I have pasted the output of dmesg for reference.

I installed nvidia drivers and cuda for running my deep learning project

I have shared a github gist of the dmesg log.

https://gist.github.com/aceakshay2/27ce181a1b392c893125ed8c1beb2f18

Any solution to reduce startup time would be appreciated

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to diagnose/fix very slow boot on Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1030867/how-to-diagnose-fix-very-slow-boot-on-ubuntu-18-04)

Comment: What is the output of systemd-analyze blame?

Comment: @JoepieEs Ths is the output of  systemd-analyze  https://gist.github.com/aceakshay2/3dc5ad77b00052aa5d79a2111c85a3c4

Answer (score 0):

Are you it in Virtual Box, or do you use it on your system? These drivers takes the most time to load. And Plymouth 29 sec. This 29 you can shave off. You can edit the file /etc/default/grub file so that the string noplymouth is included in the GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT line, for example:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash noplymouth"
```

Then run this command to update GRUB:

```
sudo update-grub
```

And reboot.
On this site you will find more tips and tricks to reduce boot-time. https://orangesputnik.org/ubuntu-desktop-optimization/. And of course there is Dr Google and Youtube. If you have the space always make backups first.