# my computer is taking long time to boot ubuntu help

Tags: boot

systemd-analyze blame

```
50.516s plymouth-quit-wait.service
16.771s snapd.service
14.694s networkd-dispatcher.service
12.193s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
11.487s snapd.seeded.service
10.048s udisks2.service
 9.721s power-profiles-daemon.service
 9.621s polkit.service
 9.345s systemd-udev-settle.service
 8.911s dev-sda4.device
 7.682s accounts-daemon.service
 7.640s avahi-daemon.service
 7.636s NetworkManager.service
 7.633s bluetooth.service
 6.940s gpu-manager.service
 6.638s cups.service
 5.793s apport.service
 5.353s gdm.service
 5.302s ModemManager.service
 4.719s rsyslog.service
 4.705s grub-common.service
 4.391s systemd-journal-flush.service
 4.261s switcheroo-control.service
 4.223s thermald.service
 4.216s wpa_supplicant.service
 4.214s systemd-logind.service
 3.426s casper-md5check.service
 3.416s e2scrub_reap.service
 2.446s systemd-udevd.service
 2.280s packagekit.service
 1.795s systemd-resolved.service
 1.657s apparmor.service
 1.551s systemd-modules-load.service
 1.183s dev-loop6.device
 1.179s systemd-sysusers.service
 1.157s snapd.apparmor.service
 1.095s systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
 1.080s keyboard-setup.service
 1.044s dev-loop10.device
 1.039s dev-loop9.device
 1.028s systemd-udev-trigger.service
 1.007s snap-snapd\x2ddesktop\x2dintegration-14.mount   964ms systemd-sysctl.service   947ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service  
894ms dev-loop5.device   857ms ua-timer.service   834ms
zfs-volume-wait.service   820ms swapfile.swap   818ms
grub-initrd-fallback.service   803ms dev-loop7.device   781ms
update-notifier-download.service   700ms dev-loop4.device   632ms
upower.service   585ms snap-bare-5.mount   584ms
snap-core18-2409.mount   583ms dev-loop2.device   542ms
dev-loop8.device   541ms snap-core20-1434.mount   540ms
systemd-journald.service   529ms systemd-random-seed.service   507ms
lvm2-monitor.service   496ms snap-core20-1494.mount   457ms
dev-loop1.device   407ms dev-loop3.device   389ms user@1000.service 
379ms systemd-oomd.service   373ms systemd-rfkill.service   372ms
snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d38\x2d2004-106.mount   362ms
snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d38\x2d2004-99.mount   358ms
zfs-load-module.service   356ms
systemd-backlight@backlight:intel_backlight.service   349ms
snap-snap\x2dstore-582.mount   343ms systemd-timesyncd.service  
335ms snap-gtk\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-1534.mount   324ms
systemd-remount-fs.service   309ms snap-snap\x2dstore-575.mount  
265ms dev-hugepages.mount   264ms dev-mqueue.mount   263ms
sys-kernel-debug.mount   262ms sys-kernel-tracing.mount   218ms
colord.service   214ms zfs-mount.service   209ms setvtrgb.service  
203ms rtkit-daemon.service   202ms snap-snapd-15177.mount   193ms
ufw.service   190ms snap-snapd-15904.mount   180ms dev-loop12.device
50.516s plymouth-quit-wait.service
16.771s snapd.service
14.694s networkd-dispatcher.service
12.193s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
11.487s snapd.seeded.service
10.048s udisks2.service
 9.721s power-profiles-daemon.service
 9.621s polkit.service
 9.345s systemd-udev-settle.service
 8.911s dev-sda4.device
 7.682s accounts-daemon.service
 7.640s avahi-daemon.service
 7.636s NetworkManager.service
 7.633s bluetooth.service
 6.940s gpu-manager.service
 6.638s cups.service
 5.793s apport.service
 5.353s gdm.service
 5.302s ModemManager.service
 4.719s rsyslog.service
 4.705s grub-common.service
 4.391s systemd-journal-flush.service
 4.261s switcheroo-control.service
```

Comment: Run `systemd-analyze critical-chain` to learn which of those services are actually delaying your boot (jobs run in parallel when possible). Then research each of those important services to decide what to do about them.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to diagnose/fix very slow boot on Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1030867/how-to-diagnose-fix-very-slow-boot-on-ubuntu-18-04)