# Ubuntu 22.04, slow boot with screen messages

Tags: boot, 22.04

Does not seem to affect the machine when I am using it. I suspect it is causing the boot time to be longer than necessary though. I am a new user and thus will need to be guided like a little child. I'm pretty sure the machine is waiting for me to do something but I am too ignorant to know what that is.
Here is the complete notification on boot screen.

```
[    0.004670] __common_interrupt: 1.55 No irq handler for vector
[    0.004670] __common_interrupt: 2.55 No irq handler for vector
[    0.004670] __common_interrupt: 3.55 No irq handler for vector
[    0.698565] platform MSFT0101:00: failed to claim resource 0: [mem 0x9fb6e000
-0x9fc6dfff]
[    0.698582] acpi MSFT0101:00: platform device creation failed: -16
[    0.865631] tpm_crb MSFT0101:00: can't request region for resource [mem 0x9fb
6e000-0x9fc6dfff]
```

Comment: If your system doesn't proceed, then it is a problem. The system doesn't expect any input from you. If the system boots, then it is normal.

Comment: Thank you for your response. The system boots and runs fine.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to diagnose/fix very slow boot on Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1030867/how-to-diagnose-fix-very-slow-boot-on-ubuntu-18-04)